# Dynamically add active class to an acf group

Tags: php, wordpress

How Can i add dynamically active class in this code? I have tried using $i=0 in nested if loop with $i== at end of nested is loop. but it seems not working.

```
    <div class="tab-content mt-5">
                        <?php
                        if (have_rows('whats_included', 2959)) {
                            while (have_rows('whats_included', 2959)) {
                                the_row();
                                if (have_rows('list_data', 2959)) {
                                    
                                    while (have_rows('list_data', 2959)) {
                                        the_row();
                        ?>
                                        <div id="<?= the_sub_field('id'); ?>" class="container tab-pane active"><br>
                                            <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                    <div class="talabat-clone-wrap radius5">
                                                        <img src="<?= bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/assets/images/talabat-app/triangle.png" class="triangle-shape" alt="">
                                                        <p><?= the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                        <?php
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue,thank you.

```
        <div class="tab-content mt-5">
                            <?php
                            $i = 0;
                            if (have_rows('whats_included', 2959)) {
                                while (have_rows('whats_included', 2959)) {
                                    the_row();
                                    if (have_rows('list_data', 2959)) {
    
                                        while (have_rows('list_data', 2959)) {
                                            the_row();
                            ?>
                                            <div id="<?= the_sub_field('id'); ?>" class="container tab-pane <?php if ($i++ == 1) : echo 'active';endif; ?>"><br>
                                                <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
                                                    <div class="col-lg-8">
                                                        <div class="talabat-clone-wrap radius5">
                                                            <img src="<?= bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/assets/images/talabat-app/triangle.png" class="triangle-shape" alt="">
                                                            <p><?= the_sub_field('text'); ?></p>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
```